# How to parse nested array of json objects using typescripts and show it in primeng component

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, nested

I am new to Angular js. Have a task of parsing nested array of json objects using typescripts and show it in primeng table. Primeng is absolutely new. I am able to show flat structure json, but this nested array of objects are creating problem.

I need to show it in some master-detail relationship.

Below is the JSON structure:

```
[
{
    "baId": "50509060-48e5-4241-a346-f834b22bf4b5",
    "status": "Pending",
    "legalName": "Koch Suppy and Trading LLP",
    "internal": true,
    "baType": "Vendor",
    "creditAddress": [
        {
            "addressSubType": "USA",
            "addressLine1": "F-35 10th Main",
            "addressLine2": "5th Cross Avenue",
            "city": "Los Angeles",
            "county": "Los Angeles",
            "state": "California",
            "country": "US",
            "postalCode": "90001",
            "notes": "District 10"
        }
    ],
    "invoiceAddress": [
        {
            "addressSubType": "USA",
            "addressLine1": "F-35 10th Main",
            "addressLine2": "5th Cross Avenue",
            "city": "Los Angeles",
            "county": "Los Angeles",
            "state": "California",
            "country": "US",
            "postalCode": "90001",
            "notes": "District 10"
        }
    ],
    "finance": [
        {
            "bank": "Citi Bank",
            "routingNumber": "C044072324",
            "accountNumber": "000123456789",
            "wireTransferMethod": "RTGS",
            "intermediaryBank": "Citi Bank",
            "intermediaryRoutingNumber": "C044072327",
            "intermediaryAccountNumber": "000123456789",
            "locationName": "Wichita"
        }
    ],
    "reportingTags": [
        {
            "leiName": "Koch Suppy and Trading LLP",
            "leiNumber": "5299001hxs",
            "782a": "54-2024246",
            "782aCountryIdentifier": "US",
            "782c": "1905-0174",
            "782cCountryIdentifier": "US",
            "cftcClassifications": "Disaggregated Futures",
            "cftcReporting": "Long Format",
            "cftcSefAssoc": "360 Trading Networks, Inc.",
            "emirCategorization": "Financial Counterparties",
            "epaCountryIdentifier": "US",
            "epaNumber": "1234-000",
            "mifidClassifications": "Retail Clients",
            "rfcCode": "EOPAN006",
            "rfcCodeCountryIdentifier": "US",
            "cpCode": "AS101",
            "systemSpecific": "AEDP"
        }
    ],
    "audit": {
        "createdBy": "koch\\malhota1",
        "modifiedBy": "koch\\malhota1",
        "creationDate": "2017-10-20T16:00:00Z",
        "modificationDate": "2027-10-20T16:00:00Z",
        "isCurrent": true
    }
}
]
```

Please help me in creating a angular project with primeng from scratch using above json. Appreciate the quick help.

Comment: What have you tried? You're pretty much asking us to do your work for you.

Comment: Its not like that. I did some work of creating interfaces and exporting them. creating a service to get the json and map it to my interface. i created a datatable_component.ts and implemented ngInit{}... My problem is i am not able to achieve the master-detail structure. I need typescript as well as html for primeng .